# tornando mensagem de erro de variavel?

Tags: javascript, html5, socket.io

ola pessoal tenho um servdor e ele esta dando um erro simples mas nao sei como resolver sendo que os objetos estao aparentemente normal veja o codigo abaixo.

```
  var io = require('socket.io').listen(8000);

   var players = {}, count = 0;

io.sockets.on('connection',
    function (socket)
    {   
        var id = count++; //assign number
        var player = players[id] = new Player(id, 10, 10); //create new      player
    player.socket = socket;


    socket.on('chat',
        function (data)
        {
            var message = player.name + ': ' + data.message;
            socket.emit('chat', { message: message});
            socket.broadcast.emit('chat', { message: message});
        });

    socket.on('position',
        function (data)
        {
            player.x = data.playerX;
            player.y = data.playerY;
            player.z = data.z;


            socket.emit('position', {pid : player.id, playerX : player.x, playerY : player.y, z : player.z});
            socket.broadcast.emit('position', {pid : player.id, playerX : player.x, playerY : player.y, z : player.z});
        }); 

    socket.on('register',
        function (name)
        {
            player.name = name;
            player.registered = true;
            socket.emit('chat', { message : "Server: bem vindo ao server " + player.name + '!'});
            socket.broadcast.emit('chat', { message : "Server: bem vindo ao server " + player.name + '!'});

            for(var p in players)
            {
                //send initial update
                if(!players[p].disconnected)
                { 
                    socket.emit('addPlayer', {pid: players[p].id, x: players[p].x, y: players[p].y, name: players[p].name, sessionid: socket.id});
                    if(players[p].id != player.id)
                        players[p].socket.emit('addPlayer', {pid: player.id, x: player.x, y: player.y, name: player.name})
                }
            }

        });

    socket.on('disconnect',
        function (socket)
        {
            player.disconnected = true;
            delete players[player.id];
            player = null;
        });

});



 function Player(id, x, y, z) {
    this.id = id;
   this.x = x;
   this.y = y;
   this.z = z;
    this.name = "";
    this.disconnected = false;
    this.registered = false;
    this.socket = null;
 }
```

liga o servidor normal mas quando ele vai receber os dados aparece a mensagem de

```
this.z = z;
```

"this.z = z is not defined"

desde ja agradeço, lembrando que é um servidor tcp ip socket.io nodejs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você não passou, ele não acha:

```
function Player(id, x, y) {
```

Onde está o `z`?

Comment: agora esta dando erro de z is not defined.

Comment: @adailtonmoraes `Player(id, 10, 10);` <- 3 argumentos, mas aqui tens 4 -> `function Player(id, x, y, Z) {`... não estás a passar o quarto argumento.

Comment: se você tem 4 argumentos na sua função, precisa de 4 argumentos ao declará-la mesmo que seja vazio, precisa declarar... js é diferente de php que se não passa ele entende como null. passa assim Player(10,10,10,10) ou pelo menos Player(10,10,10,"").

Comment: mesmo assim nao funciona deu erro do mesmo geito coloquei assim Player(id, 10, 10, 1);  function Player(id, x, y, Z) { nao funfou.

Comment: se o z q pega na aplicação é minusculo, o seu z da declaração tem que ser também. Tenta atualizar sua pergunta com o código como ta agora que facilita.

Comment: mesmo com o z em minusculo deu  erro. newplayer (id, 10, 10, z) deu erro z is not defined

Comment: ta, esse this.id existe, o this.z existe? outra coisa, no código atualizado, voce ainda ta passando o z na declaração da função maiusculo  Player(id, x, y, Z)

Comment: no caso o z ou numero ficaria com as propriedades iguais as do 10,10 ou seja o z seria para representar um valor que o cliente de algum usuario do chat mandasse mas com um valor de 0 a 10 entende?

Comment: cara, se voce passa  Player(id, x, y, Z) o Z maiusculo, no seu código voce precisa colocar this.z = Z (maisculo), case sensitive, entende? z é diferente de Z, a != A....

Comment: @adailtonmoraes és tu que marca como resolvido/aceite na resposta.

Comment: só uma ultima perguntinha na linha  player.z = data.z; e na transmissao de dados nao esta acontecendo nada:    z : player.z});  nao esta me transmitindo nada.

Comment: É... esse método eu nunca usei... mas boa sorte ai com o js

Comment: resolvi, era no cliente.